# Lookbehind in Javascript : don't match if multiple characters before

Tags: javascript, regex

see https://regex101.com/r/463Qpm/1/

I want to match Bb and Dd in this case

```
Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd
```

But not in this case when there is { and a few characters

```
{Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd
```

I tried this regex but I have error with + I can't find the right syntax :

```
(?<!{[A-Za-z]+)(?<=:\s)[A-Za-z][a-z]*
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, lookbehinds are not universally supported in JS.

Comment: Do you mean `(?<!{.*)(?<=:\s*)[A-Za-z][a-z]*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/463Qpm/3))?

Comment: Also, your regex101 link is using PHP's PCRE2 but your question is tagged Javascript.

Comment: You can rule out the `{[A-Za-z]+` by matching it and the rest of the line. Using an alternation, you can capture the values in a capture group 1. `{[A-Za-z].*|:\s([A-Za-z][a-z]*)` See https://regex101.com/r/VoMu5m/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Your solution can be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing with the support for lookbehind, the pattern that you tried `(?<!{[A-Za-z]+)(?<=:\s)[A-Za-z][a-z]*` matches in both cases because both assertions are true  at the position before `Bb` and `Dd`.

There is `:\s` directly to the left, and there is not `{[A-Za-z]+` directly to the left because it is not possible to have both and the assertion therefore is true.

Note to [see this page](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind) for the support of lookbehind in Javascript.

---

One option without using lookarounds could be using a capture group with an alternation, first ruling out what you do not want. Then capture in a group what you want to keep.

```
{[A-Za-z].*|:\s([A-Za-z][a-z]*)
```

The pattern matches

- `{[A-Za-z].*` Match `{`,  a char A-Za-z and the rest of the line
- `|` Or
- `:\s` Match `:` and a whitespace char
- `([A-Za-z][a-z]*)` Capture group 1, match a char A-Za-z followed by optional chars a-z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VoMu5m/1)

```js
const regex = /{[A-Za-z].*|:\s([A-Za-z][a-z]*)/g;
[
  'Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd',
  '{Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd'
].forEach(str => {
  const result = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
  if (result[0] !== undefined) {
    console.log(result);
  }
})
```

Another option using a single lookbehind could be asserting that there is no `{` at the left from the start of the string followed by asserting `:\s`

```
 (?<=^[^{]*:\s)[A-Za-z][a-z]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yBGge5/1)

```js
    const regex = /(?<=^[^{]*:\s)[A-Za-z][a-z]*/g;
    [
        'Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd',
        '{Aa : Bb, Cc : Dd'
    ].forEach(str => {
        const result = str.match(regex);
        if (result) {
            console.log(result)    
        }        
    })
```